# Cannot connect to Apache when changing the default Apache port to 803 on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, port

I installed httpd on CentOS 7 and changed the Apache port 80 to `Listen 803` and restarted the httpd.

Checked with `netstat -pln | grep -i 803`, it says it listening.

But I am still unable to reload the Apache test page, while after changing the port to 80 back again, the page is loading fine. What might I be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

And after running that you should see the following output:

```
Output Syntax OK
```

If you don't, then you misconfigured your Apache2 VirtualHosts. If did see that, then you should run:

```
systemctl status httpd
```

And check if there is any problem. If it was running, then run:

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default
```

Also make sure to open port 803 by running:

```
sudo ufw allow 803
```

And go to:

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

And add `Listen 803` below `Listen 80`.

then run:

```
 sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

then change:

```
 port number: 80 to 803
```

Then run `systemctl restart httpd` and bam.

If it didn't work, then [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7) might help you.

Comment: I installed httpd on centos host, made entry Listen 803 in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and when trying to systemctl restart httpd getting this error "Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details"  and systemctl status httpd.service says this  "(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:803".

Comment: I added the port 803 with command semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 803 started httpd successfully, still Ip:803 is not working in browser.

Comment: Hey, did you open the port by running `sudo ufw allow 803`?

Comment: Also I missed the biggest thing.

Run:
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
Then:
`port:80 to 803`
Then run:
`systemctl restart httpd`

Comment: As i am running centos 7, installed ufw and when running ufw allow 803, it gives  "ERROR: problem running"

Comment: Hey, just purge ufw then take a loot at this article. Im pretty sure it will help you!
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7